# How can this circuit operate in the \$R_L \to \infty\$ limit?

Tags: analog

As per the title, how can this circuit operate in the \$R_L \to \infty\$ limit when it seems to mean that current flowing from the supply has nowhere to go? I ask because my text seems to analyze this circuit in this limit without mention.

[image]

More generally, in an emitter-follower or source-follower amplifier, is the resistor between the emitter or source necessary? Note that as per the diagram, \$R_L\$ should not be considered (I think) part of the load seen by this stage, but rather part of the stage itself.

Comment: So let's analyze the wording first, as long as the resistor is there, the value can be as high as you want and will it matter? It's still there, and for any uncountably large value of resistance, there will be an uncountably small value of current, correct?

Comment: You seem to be posting section after section of your textbook/coursework and asking for explanations of each one. We can't go through the whole book this way. When there's so many of them, it's really you looking for tuition and discussion and that's not what the site's about. On this scale, your learning looks better served by you researching for yourself.

Comment: Rl->infinity means it migh be open circuit so there will be voltage at output which is (vi-VGS)

Comment: @Justme I agree, though we do run into the problem of being out of saturation as we crank up that resistor value.

Comment: @TonyM My apologies if this is against site policy, but I really have been grateful to have learned and gotten help with things I didn't understand even after a few readings. I do promise it's not something I do frivolously. I read very closely and often my questions are about something the authors mention offhand without (I think) enough substance for me to be able to understand it without external help. Given that I am self-studying, I have very much appreciated the opportunity to learn from people much more knowledgeable than me.

Comment: Again, if asking textbook-related questions is against site policy then I will desist, though I should note that I am asking questions related to two of the most popular books around (Gray and Hurst for analog and Weste and Harris for VLSI).

Comment: Each question is perfectly OK in its own right but I'm talking about them seen as an ever-increasing pile. I'm very much all for you getting the chance to present your predicaments and benefit from the answers, it just may not be the most efficient way for you to learn i.e. they could be much better ways for you to progress and faster. And I'm certainly very keen to support and encourage anyone who wants to learn and to put the work in. But no, what you're doing in each individual question certainly isn't against site policy, not that I can see.

Comment: Much appreciated, really! I am currently on a month-long break and am therefore doing my best to devour as much of each of these books as I can (hence the rather large number of questions). I do promise that they are only a small cross-section (namely, the sections I can't figure out!) of everything I'm coming across. But your point is well-taken -- I will try to be even more deliberate about when/what/how I post. @TonyM

Comment: It's a more subtle thing: it's not against site policy, no, but I notice you haven't submitted any answers, so one could gather an impression of freeloading. Which makes some readers less inclined to contribute, or to contribute as much quality or positivity as they would otherwise.

Comment: Understood, I will look to start doing that. To be honest, I worry that I am not at a level to be answering most questions but perhaps that’s not correct. @TimWilliams

Comment: @EE18 checkout this video it explains how mosfet acts as pass transistor and output voltage of it explained  it can be considered Rl->infity which explain my previous commenton Vo=Vi-vt https://youtu.be/naCghpy0wqo?si=s3PLC53edLw8XaoG

Comment: @Justme: Be careful with your terminology. "Infinite" is not the same thing as "[uncountable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncountable_set)". There are countable infinities and uncountable infinities.

Comment: Generally speaking, infinities in electronics are continuous, and the cardinality (a number theoretic thing) is irrelevant; particular values are uncountable anyway as we mostly work in the real or complex sets. By continuity, I mean specifically that values out at +/-infinity (for complex, in any direction) are equivalent to 1/x for x near zero (or complex 1/z for z near zero along any direction). This is simply the duality of admittance and impedance, and it's perfectly reasonable to have an impedance near zero (+/-), or infinity (+/-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem, as discussed in comments elsewhere, was in not understanding what this diagram was conveying. It is of course true that this circuit does not operate as intended in the \$R_L \to \infty \$ limit. However, saying that misses what the diagram is really a shorthand for: it is depicting a small-signal scenario with respect to everything *other* than the MOSFET. This is a fairly standard convention in analog circuits textbooks (and, indeed, in Gray and Hurst, from where this book is taken). In this light, there is nothing wrong with this circuit: this \$R_L\$ is, in reality, the small signal resistance of the transistor current source which is biasing this CD stage.

Answer (score 1):

Infinity is a mathematical object. Mathematical objects aren't real: they only exist in human minds. Nothing is really infinite. Mathematical objects are often effective at modeling real things, but you must be aware that their unreality can lead to trouble with your thinking.

Here, you are confusing the model with reality. In the model, no current needs to flow, and the circuit works fine in the infinite limit. In reality, there is no such thing as an infinite resistor, and none of your other idealized components exist, either. So, as you note, the limit is impossible.

This is why reading and solving paper problems isn't enough to learn this stuff. It's necessary to get some parts, connect them together, make lights come on and beepers beep, along with the inevitable smoke and sparks when you make a mistake (and we all make them).

Comment: I am confused about why the model works even in the infinite limit. No current flows, so how does the circuit work? The transistor is no longer in saturation, right?

Comment: @EE18 It works as long as the current is nonzero, no matter how small. Then, for zero current, well, that's what the "limit" concept in mathematics is for.

Comment: But even as we raise the resistance up, eventually that source node voltage will get too high, no?

Comment: @EE18 In math, no. In reality, maybe.

Answer (score -2):

It doesn't operate predictably, if you let RL grow with no limits. Finally all kinds of leaks take the dominant role when the current gets smaller. But the math formula of Vo can well have the limit value, if you assume some Vi, some Vdd and some math model for the mosfet. Do not expect the result presents anything else than your assumptions.

One easy assumption for the behaviour of the mosfet is to assume the Id is proportional to the square of Vgs-Vt where Vt is the treshold voltage. The law is useful when there's so high Vdd and so low Id that the channel pinching is the major Id limiting process and there's some substantial Vds as a consequence.

So, if we

- write Id = A(Vgs-Vt)^2
- remember that Vgs = Vi-Vo and
- let RL grow with no limit. Then Id=Vo/RL approaches zero and we get

Vo approaches Vi-Vt.

Do not believe it happens in practice, too. A resistor with infinite resistance is impossible. You cannot measure Vo because the meter takes some current, the effective RL is not bigger that the resistance of the meter. In addition when RL grows, all kinds of leaks grow substantial (as percentages). The Id modeled by the equation has finally a minor role.

But there can be a range of quite big RL values where Vo = Vi-Vt within the measuring tolerance. Deciding mathematically what that RL range is and does such range really exist is impossible without having a more precise model of the mosfet.

Comment: Open circuit is considered infinite resistance since no current flows through it. So if you remove Rl it's infinite resistance.

Comment: @Ch.SivaRamKishore It's not. It doesn't exist.